# ODE solution with variation of constants verification

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I am not sure how to verify my solution is correct as the matrix $A$ is a function of $t$. I want to solve the following IVP with the variation of constants formula.
\begin{equation}
x'=\begin{pmatrix}2t&0\\0&3\end{pmatrix}x + \begin{pmatrix}t\\1\end{pmatrix}, x(0)=\begin{pmatrix}0\\2\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

The solution I have derived is:
\begin{equation}
x(t) = \begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}e^{t^2}\\-\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{7}{3}e^{3t}\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Is this correct? If not I will post more details.

Comment: @CodeKinPlusPlus: Oops, sign error on $(1/2)$ term, should be $-(1/2)$. Quick check when you do these is to check $x(0)$ and see if it gives the IC. Top solution should be $-(1/2) + (1/2)e^{t^2}$. Sorry. Everything else is spot on, so likely you just transcribed a sign incorrectly.

Comment: It's probably better if you show your work instead of just your answer so that we can "troubleshoot" what's wrong here

Comment: @Amzoti Actually I just copied this down wrong from my paper and I do have the $-\dfrac{1}{2}$! I actually tried checking this in sage and for the top component I was getting a term multiplied by $t$. I don't trust sage anymore...

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: It is likely a new bug that was introduced and a bug report or at least reporting it to them would help cause the other problem we discovered was driving me batty! SAGE is an amazing program and a wonderful idea, but it is massive and sometimes people make mistakes. Regards and keep up the great work!

Answer (score 1):

First thing to notice about this system is that it's *uncoupled*: the two unknown functions do not interact. This is the result of the matrix being diagonal.

So, you can solve the equations one by one. By hand, or in Sage. First equation:

```
var('t')
x=function('x',t)
desolve(diff(x,t)-2*t*x-t,x,[0,0])
```

Output: $\dfrac12 \exp(-t^2)-\dfrac12 $. Second equation:

```
var('t')
y=function('y',t)
desolve(diff(y,t)-3*y-1,y,[0,2])
```

Output: $\dfrac73 \exp(-3t)-\dfrac13$.

Meanwhile, `desolve_system` is acting odd when given the same system to solve:

> TypeError: ECL says: Error executing code in Maxima: algsys: tried and failed to reduce system to a polynomial in one variable; give up.

Sounds like a question for [ask Sage](http://ask.sagemath.org/) (which sadly is still an SE 1.0 site), or a bug report.

Comment: (Tested in Sage online notebook running version 5.4)